Importing python module from another package
I'm learning python and looking to follow conventions for organizing my repo. Currently it's structured something like this:
repo
  src
    __init__.py <- empty
    function1.py
  test
    __init__.py <- empty
    testFunction1.py

I thought that would allow me to start testFunction1.py with from src import function1 or from src.function1 import * but I get "No module named 'src'".
What's the best practice with packages / modules?

It also matters which directory you're in when you run python, e.g. if you cd repo/tests and do python testFunction1.py then you will get get that error. The package import paths are resolved relative to where python interpreter was launched from.

you may have to add folder /path/to/repo (without src or test) to list sys.path before you use import src or import test - because python uses all paths from sys.path to search module/folder (and it will find src and test in /path/to/repo from list sys.path)
